# Using multithreading optimize the execution time (simple example)

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, boost, concurrency

I have the following code:

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp> 
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp> 
#include <iostream> 

int main() 
{ 
  boost::posix_time::ptime start = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time(); 

  boost::uint64_t sum = 0; 
  for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) 
    sum += i; 

  boost::posix_time::ptime end = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time(); 
  std::cout << end - start << std::endl; 

  std::cout << sum << std::endl; 
}
```

The task is: refactor the following program to calculate the total using two threads. Since many processors nowadays have two cores, the execution time should decrease by utilizing threads.

Here is my solution:

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp> 
#include <iostream> 


boost::uint64_t s1 = 0;
boost::uint64_t s2 = 0;

void sum1() 
{ 
  for (int i = 0; i < 500000000; ++i) 
    s1 += i; 
} 

void sum2()
{ 
  for (int i = 500000000; i < 1000000000; ++i) 
    s2 += i; 
}


int main() 
{ 
    boost::posix_time::ptime start = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

    boost::thread t1(sum1); 
    boost::thread t2(sum2); 

    t1.join(); 
    t2.join();

    boost::posix_time::ptime end = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time(); 
    std::cout << end - start << std::endl; 

    std::cout << s1+s2 << std::endl; 
}
```

Please review and also answer the following questions:
1. Why this code does not actually optimize the execution time? :) (I use Intel Core i5 processor, and Win7 64bit system)
2. Why when I use one variable *s* to store the sum instead of *s1* and *s2* the sum becomes incorrect?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this homework? That's fine but you should say.

Comment: `s = 1000000000; s = s*(s-1)/2`

Comment: I don't get your first question, what do you mean "it does not actually optimize execution time?" Doesn't it run 2x faster now?

Comment: you should assert that `1000000000` doesn't exceed the range of `int` for your platform.

Comment: this question belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This task is from this site: http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/ . It is my homework which I have assigned myself :))))

Comment: @Karine: Can you please explain your first question better? Are you not seeing any speedup after adding threads?

Comment: Yes, yes! There is no time shrink with two threads.

Answer (score 4):

I'll answer your second question, because the first one is not yet clear to me. When you are using a single global variable to calculate the sum there is a so-called "data race" caused by the fact that the operation

```
s += i;
```

is not "atomic", meaning that at the assembler level it is translated into several instructions. If one thread is executing this set of instructions it may be interrupted by another thread doing the same thing and your results will be inconsistent.

This is due to the fact that threads are scheduled on and off the CPU by the OS and it's impossible to predict how the threads will interleave their instruction execution.

The classic pattern in this case is to have two local variables collecting the sums for each thread and then summing them up together into a global variable once the threads have fished their work.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer the first:

It takes a lot more time to create a thread than it takes to do nothing (base).

the compiler will convert this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) 
     sum += i;
```

into this:

```
//    << optimized away >>
```

even your worst case using local data, it would be one addition with optimization enabled.

The parallel version reduces the compiler's ability to optimize the program, while adding work.

Comment: I guess this is not the reason. Because, I changed the code for both cases to print a small text for each iteration. (And decreased the iteration number to 10000.) The execution lasted about 38.5 seconds for both codes.

Comment: @Karine and if you ran it in a profiler, you would see that it spends all its time printing.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to refactor the program (code-wise) to compute the sum using multiple threads is to use [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/):

```
// $ g++ -fopenmp parallel-sum.cpp && ./a.out
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>

const int32_t N = 1 << 30;

int main() {
  int64_t sum = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
  for (int32_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    sum += i;

  std::cout << sum << " " << static_cast<int64_t>(N)*(N-1)/2 << std::endl;
}
```

#### Output

```
576460751766552576 576460751766552576
```

---

Here's a parallel reduction implemented using c++11 threads:

```
// $ g++ -std=c++0x -pthread parallel-sum-c++11.cpp && ./a.out
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

namespace {
  std::mutex mutex;

  void sum_interval(int32_t start, int32_t end, int64_t &sum) {
    int64_t s = 0;
    for ( ; start < end; ++start) s += start;

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    sum += s; 
  }
}

int main() {
  int64_t sum = 0;
  const int num_threads = 4;
  const int32_t N = 1 << 30;
  std::thread t[num_threads];

  // fork threads; assign intervals to sum
  int32_t start = 0, step = N / num_threads;
  for (int i = 0; i < num_threads-1; ++i, start += step)
    t[i] = std::thread(sum_interval, start, start+step, std::ref(sum));
  t[num_threads-1] = std::thread(sum_interval, start, N, std::ref(sum));

  // wait for result and print it
  for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) t[i].join();
  std::cout << sum << " " << static_cast<int64_t>(N)*(N-1)/2 << std::endl;
}
```

Note: Access to `sum` is guarded so only one thread at a time can change it. If `sum` is `std::atomic<int64_t>` then the locking can be omitted.

Comment: I agree that this is the best solution for this kind of problems. Unless the OP is constrained to use boost threads, I would recommend this approach instead.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to 1 should be: run in a profiler and see what it tells you.

But there is at least one usual suspect: False sharing. Your s1 and s2 likely end up on the same cacheline, so your 2 cores (if your 2 threads indeed end up on different cores) have to synchronize at the cacheline level. Make sure the 2 uint64_t are on different cachelines (whose size depends on the architecture you're targeting).

As to the answer to 2... Nothing in your program guarantees that the updates from one thread will not get stomped by the second and vice-versa. You need either synchronization primitives to make sure your updates don't happen at the same time, or atomic updates to make sure the updates don't stomp on each other.

Comment: What is profiler? I use VS Express 2010, does it have profiler?

Comment: A profiler is a program that analyzes the execution of your application, using processor-specific features, to tell you where the processor spends its time and why. I don't know if VS Express 2010 comes with one. You can google for information on profilers for sure. The main point of the first sentence is however that performance is not something where guessing gets you anywhere. Measure, measure, measure.